# Campo varchar no guarda dato completo

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una Base de Datos en **SQL Server**, y el problema está en una tabla, en ella definí un campo tipo **varchar**, con una **longitud de 250 caracteres**. El problema comienza aquí, estaba haciendo unas pruebas, actualizando el mismo campo con diferentes datos en un mismo registro, *(básicamente insertando diferentes cadenas de texto)*. Después de muchas pruebas, y en los siguientes **UPDATES** que hice, el campo en ese mismo registro comenzó a *"Limitar, o Cortar"*, los datos que ingresaba.
Por ejemplo:

Yo insertaba al inicio: `"EstoEsUnEjemploDeUnTexto-123456"` y sin problemas lo insertaba, después, trato de insertar lo mismo, y solo inserta: `"EstoEsUnEjemploDeUn"`.

Lo más curioso, es que si eso mismo, o datos de más longitud *(sin exceder los 250 caracteres qué es con lo que está definido el campo)*, lo actualizo, sin problemas los otros registros en el mismo campo insertan el dato sin cortarlo. El problema solo se presenta en este campo de este registro, pues inserto en este mismo campo, otros datos, y de igual manera *"Limita, o Corta"*, el valor que inserto.

Aquí les comparto una imagen del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo la sentencia con la que estuve trabajando:

```
UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, PN 338-109-704-0 QTY 20' WHERE idPO = 22;
```

Y, entre tantos campos que posee mi tabla, aquí comparto como está definido el campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/*******************************************************************/

De primera instancia, el campo "equipement", que es donde está el problema, estaba como un campo vacio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- El **número 1**, fue como originalmente hice el primer INSERT.
- Después, estuve actualizando (UPDATE), con los **número 2, 3 y 4**. (Estuve jugando con esos, ejecutaba uno, después otro, salteados, etcétera).
  En uno de estos (no recuerdo en cual) fue cuando ya no comenzó a actualizar de manera correcta.
- El **número 5** lo utilicé de ejemplo, para ver si con otros caracteres los insertaba.
- El **número 6** fue para ver si poniendo el campo como NULL y volver a insertar funcionaba.

Esos fueron los ejemplos que fui utilizando, los **numeros 2 al 4** los intenté en el registro 13, y ahí no da error, si agrega cualquier dato sin cortarlo.

Espero alguien me pueda orientar, ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías poner la definición de tu tabla y algunos ejemplos de lo que realizaste insert y update

Comment: los agregaré al post original.

Comment: A que te refieres con que insertas y lo corta, osea la primera vez lo hace bien y despues ya no? sigues teniendo este error? Podrias poner lo que estas haciendo como lo estas haciendo

Comment: En el registro con el _"idPO"_ número 22, estoy haciendo el mismo **UPDATE** que definí en el post original. 
El dato completo que estoy poniendo es: **'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, PN 338-109-704-0 QTY 20'**, la sentencia se ejecuta sin problemas o errores. Cuando reviso con un _"SELECT * FROM"_, en ese campo, donde inserté el dato, no está completo, de acuerdo a como yo lo había actualizado. La segunda imagen que puse, en el registro con **idPO 13**, si inserta el dato completo, pero el registro con **idPO 22** (es donde se presenta el error), solo toma después de la "coma" 5 caracteres más.

Comment: Y si haces el update con el dato correspondiente no lo actualiza entonces?

Comment: En este mismo registro, el 23, si pruebo insertando otro tipo de valor o cadenas de texto al azar, los inserta, pero, si excedo cierto número de caracteres, vuelve a cortar esa misma cadena.

Comment: Esos ejemplos que realizas necesito ver para tratar de replicar el error muestrame como lo estas insertarndo y luego como lo estas actualizando y despues que realizas

Comment: No, no actualiza, pero si ese mismo dato lo inserto en otro registro y en el mismo campo, lo inserta sin problemas.

Comment: Enseñame una seria de pasos de lo que haces para tratar de ayudarte

Comment: Los agrego al post original.

Comment: De acuerdo ....

Comment: Puedes ponerlo como texto y no como imagen de favor

Comment: 1. INSERT INTO PODATA(PO, equipement) VALUES('TEST0014269997', '');
2. UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, PN 338-109-704-0 QTY 20' WHERE idPO = 22;
3. UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, GM 370-109-704-0 QTY 20' WHERE idPO = 22;
4. UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, FL 001-132-704-0 QTY 50' WHERE idPO = 22;
5. UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ' WHERE idPO = 22;
6. UPDATE PODATA SET equipement = NULL WHERE idPO = 22;

Comment: El error como lo mencionas no se puede reproducir. Si estás usando variables o parámetros deberías mencionarlo también.

Comment: No, no. Nada de eso, solo estoy haciendo consultas directas tal cuales las muestro en los ejemplos.

Comment: Si utilizas `sqlcmd` desde línea de comandos o Powershell, también muestra la info truncada?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza Dbcc checkDb o DBCC checkTable. Lo que comentas, solo se puede producir por un problema en la misma, dado que además como bien indicas, solo se produce en ese registro.

Primero mira la integridad de la base antes de realizar ninguna reparación, y conforme a la info que te muestre, ya puedes pensar en un REPAIR_REBUILD o cualquier otra opción.

[Dbcc](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Si la tabla no presenta problemas, la opción siguiente, es comprobar la transacción.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(250);
SET @VAR = 'PN 338-109-804-0 QTY 1, PN 338-109-704-0 QTY 20';
DECLARE @MITABLA TABLE (ID INT, EQUIPMENT VARCHAR(250))

UPDATE PODATA SET EQUIPEMENT = @VAR 
OUTPUT INSERTED.idPo, inserted.EQUIPEMENT INTO @MITABLA
WHERE IDPO=22;

SELECT 'REGISTRO PREVIO A COMMIT: ', T.ID, T.EQUIPMENT
FROM @MITABLA T

COMMIT TRAN

SELECT 'REGISTRO POST COMMIT: ', P.IDPO, P.EQUIPEMENT
FROM PODATA P JOIN @MITABLA T ON P.idPo = T.ID

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

SELECT   
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 
           @ErrorSeverity,
           @ErrorState 
           );  
END CATCH
```

Si hay algún registro que se modifica, con output sabrás quién o quienes se modifican. Si ocurre algo, tendrás una excepción. Sino ocurre nada, tendrás una salida por pantalla, que te indicará los dos movimientos. El de output, y el contenido final de la transacción.
Puede contener algún error de sintaxis, en cuanto a los nombres de los campos.

Comment: Ya probé los dos, y no me regresan ningún tipo de error. El Log me muestra que todo está bien. :/

Comment: En la sentencia de creación no esta la tabla completa. La lógica dice, que como ya lo has mirado todo, y lo que comentas, parece imposible, hay algo que se te está escapando. Select count(*) from PODDATA where idPo=22 ¿Cuantos resultados regresa?

Comment: He añadido en la respuesta una consulta para ejecutar. Comentas como te fué.

Comment: Pongo imagen de los resultados el tu respuesta, donde está la transacción.

Comment: Elias, no veo ninguna imagen nueva. Es de suponer, que la transacción tiene que devolverte dos filas independientes. Una pone REGISTRO PREVIO A COMMIT - 22- PN......QTY-20 y la otra pone REGISTRO POST COMMIT -  22 - PN.....QTY 20. Si fue bien, pero sino fue bien tiene que devoverte un mensaje de error.